# How can I flat map from an enum list property to the enum itself?

Tags: java, enums, java-stream

Given the following enum:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum SampleEnum {
    A("aaa", Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)),
    B("bbb", Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,9)),
    C("ccc", Arrays.asList(10,11)),
    D("ddd", new ArrayList<>());

    private final String code;
    private final List<Integer> symbols;

    // It does not work on arrays 
    private static final Map<String, SampleEnum> CODE_TO_ENUM_MAP =
            stream(values()).collect(toMap(SampleEnum ::getCode, t -> t));
}
```

I want to create mapping between each symbol in the list to the enum value.

Expected map: `Integer` -> `SampleEnum`

```
1 -> A
2 -> A
3 -> A
4 -> A
5 -> B
6 -> B
7 -> B
8 -> B
9 -> B
10 -> C
11 -> C
```

How can I create this `Map<Integer, SampleEnum>`?

Comment: You could `flatMap` your lists to pairs first and collect these pairs to a map later.

Comment: @4EACH, provide a full listing, please. So we can run it.

Comment: @I.G. This is it. No duplicates between arrays and enum values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a pair:

```
static class EnumWithValue {
    SampleEnum sampleEnum;
    int value;

    public EnumWithValue(SampleEnum sampleEnum, int value) {
        this.sampleEnum = sampleEnum;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public SampleEnum getSampleEnum() {
        return sampleEnum;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use `flatMap` to create int+enum pairs:

```
private static final Map<Integer, SampleEnum > CODE_TO_ENUM_MAP =
        Arrays.stream(values())
                .flatMap(e -> e.getSymbols().stream().map(symbol -> new EnumWithValue(e, symbol)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(EnumWithValue::getValue, EnumWithValue::getSampleEnum));
```

Executing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(CODE_TO_ENUM_MAP);
}
```

Prints:

```
{1=A, 2=A, 3=A, 4=A, 5=B, 6=B, 7=B, 8=B, 9=B, 10=C, 11=C}
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
private static final Map<Integer, SampleEnum> SYMBOL_TO_ENUM_MAP =
        Arrays.stream(values())
                .flatMap(e -> e.symbols.stream().map(s -> Map.entry(s, e)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

The key insight here is using the [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) function to expand each collection of elements to a stream with an element for each.  Each element of the stream is a pair consisting of the enum itself, and the single symbol.  These pairs are then collected back into a map.

Comment: I am getting, `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Strange, this works just fine for me when I add it directly to your `SampleEnum` class.